# Read Certain Lines from File

Tags: ruby

Hi just getting into Ruby, and I am trying to learn some basic file reading commands, and I haven't found any solid sources yet.

I am trying to go through certain lines from that file, til the end of the file.

So in the file where it says FILE_SOURCES I want to read all the sources til end of file, and place them in a file.

I found printing the whole file, and replacing words in the file, but I just want to read certain parts in the file.

Comment: Take a look here http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/ruby/rb-readfile/index.html

Comment: You could be reinventing a previously invented wheel. Depending on the OS, you might want to consider using `grep` or `find` to locate the lines, and then pass them to Ruby. The `%x{}` operator or using backticks to wrap a command would be a good starting place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this (assuming you can read the entire file into memory):

```
source_lines = IO.readlines('source_file.txt')
start_line   = source_lines.index{ |line| line =~ /SOURCE_LINE/ } + 1
File.open( 'other_file.txt', 'w' ) do |f|
  f << source_lines[ start_line..-1 ].join( "\n" )
end
```

Relevant methods:

- [`IO.readlines`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/IO.html#method-c-readlines) to read the lines into an array
- [`Array#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-index) to find the index of the first line matching a regular expression
- [`File.open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/File.html#method-c-open) to create a new file on disk (and automatically close it when done)
- [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) to get the subset of lines from the index to the end

If you can't read the entire file into memory, then I'd do a simpler variation on @tadman's state-based one:

```
started = false
File.open( 'other_file.txt', 'w' ) do |output|
  IO.foreach( 'source_file.txt' ) do |line|
    if started then
      output << line
    elsif line =~ /FILE_SOURCES/
      started = true
    end
  end
end
```

*Welcome to Ruby!*

Comment: As an addendum to Phrogz' comment "assuming you can read the entire file into memory"... Slurping a file can lead to scalability problems, and can actually be slower than reading a file line-by-line because of memory allocation and reallocation. Somewhere on StackOverflow I think I have a benchmark showing read times and how to get the fastest "slurp".

Comment: Here's the benchmark and samples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445089/most-efficient-method-for-reading-input-in-ruby/4445619#4445619

Comment: It's probably better to use `line.match(...)` instead of `line =~ ...` since the later is inherited from Perl, a language not necessarily known for its readability.

Answer (score 7):

Usually you follow a pattern like this if you're trying to extract a section from a file that's delimited somehow:

```
open(filename) do |f|
  state = nil

  while (line = f.gets)
    case (state)
    when nil
      # Look for the line beginning with "FILE_SOURCES"
      if (line.match(/^FILE_SOURCES/))
        state = :sources
      end
    when :sources
      # Stop printing if you hit something starting with "END"
      if (line.match(/^END/))
        state = nil
      else
        print line
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can change from one state to another depending on what part of the file you're in.

Answer (score 2):

```
File.open("file_to_read.txt", "r") {|f|
  line = f.gets
  until line.include?("FILE_SOURCES")
    line = f.gets
  end
  File.open("file_to_write.txt", "w") {|new_file|
    f.each_line {|line|
      new_file.puts(line) 
    }
   new_file.close
  }
  f.close 
}
```

Comment: It's considered more idiomatic in Ruby to use the block form of `File.open`, and I would use it again instead of `File.new` (so that you could use the block form).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Changing it to reflect that.  I also think that I misunderstood the original question (wanting to pick up lines AFTER FILE_SOURCES, not just any line containing it).

Answer (score 0):

IO functions have no idea what "lines" in a file are. There's no straightforward way to skip to a certain line in a file, you'll have to read it all and ignore the lines you don't need.